# PHP preg_match tag + curly braces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string such as:

```
#sometag-{serialized-data-here}
```

And I want to match this ***pattern***, but **use** everything inside the curly braces (so I can unserialize it later). How can I match this text pattern with preg_match()?

So far I have:

```
preg_match('~{[^{}]*}~', $text, $match);
```

but this just matches the contents of the braces if in $text without the hash tag.

**EDIT:**  Here is the logic of what im trying to accomplish:

```
  $user_post = "Here is my cool post that contains some media.";
  $media = array("mediatype" => "sometype", "id" => "ebJ2brErERQ", "title" => "Some cool video", "description" => "Some cool description");  
  $user_post .= "#sometag-" . serialize($media);
```

Later, when I fetch $user_post from the database, I want to match the text, strip it out and display the media.

I'll have something like this:

```
Here is my cool post that contains some media.#sometag-a:4:{s:9:"mediatype";s:8:"sometype";s:2:"id";s:11:"ebJ2brErERQ";s:5:"title";s:15:"Some cool video";s:11:"description";s:21:"Some cool description";}
```

Comment: If you're matching the contents reliably, can't you just wrap your match in {}'s?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to "match everything inside the curly braces", yet you complain that it "matches the contents of the braces".

Comment: The $text is inside a user contributed post, and I dont want it matching content where a user might have curly braces. They would have to include "#sometag" that only I know

Comment: @netcoder - Yeah sorry, I've updated the question hopefully it is more clearer now.

Comment: Why don't you paste text for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use explode()?

```
$tag_data_arr = explode('-', $text, 2);
```

Comment: The last parameter is a limit, saying that you will only allow the string to be split into two pieces. So, it will match that first dash, but no others.

Comment: Right, this is a much better solution. This ensures the serialized data will always be in the [1] spot of $tag_data_arr. Right?

Comment: @barfoon: If the "$text is inside a user contributed post", how would that help?

Comment: As long as the string is always formatted like the example (with a dash as a delimiter).

Comment: @netcoder is right, though. If your string actually has a lot of other stuff besides the tag/data format string, you'll need a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Make it greedy...

```
$text = "#sometag-{hello:{}{}yooohooo}";

preg_match('/#([\w]+)\-{(.*)}/is', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Result...

```
Array
(
    [0] => #sometag-{hello:{}{}yooohooo} //everything
    [1] => sometag //tag
    [2] => hello:{}{}yooohooo //serialized data
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
preg_match('~#sometag-({[^{}]*})~', $text, $match);
```

Then:

```
echo $match[1];
```

To be a little more specific, `()` defines *subpatterns*. You can use as many as you want to match different things in a regular expression. Per example:

```
preg_match('~#(some)(tag)-({[^{}]*})~', $text, $match);
echo $match[1]; // some
echo $match[2]; // tag
echo $match[3]; // {serialized-data-here}
```

**Note:** You want want to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead.

Comment: Ahh figured out why. When it serialized it added 'a:4' before the first '{', which is why mine didnt match. Thanks